# JQuery animate has no effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm just screwing around with some HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and jQuery and for some reason my jQuery will not do anything at all.

That is, I click a circle and the animation doesn't work.
There are no errors in the console.

Am I not linking it correctly? Each file is in the same folder.

```js
$('.circle').click (function () {
    $('#c1').animate ( {
        left: '0px'
    }, 200);

    $('#c2').animate ( {
        left: '285px'
    }, 200);
} );
```

```css
.loader {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 404px;
}
.circle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 7px;
}

#c1 { background-color: #4285f4; }
#c2 { background-color: #EA4335; }
#c3 { background-color: #FCBD06; }
#c4 { background-color: #4285F4; }
#c5 { background-color: #34AA54; }
#c6 { background-color: #EA4335; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader">
    <div class="circle" id='c1'></div>
    <div class="circle" id='c2'></div>
    <div class="circle" id='c3'></div>
    <div class="circle" id='c4'></div>
    <div class="circle" id='c5'></div>
    <div class="circle" id='c6'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: The CSS "left" property doesn't do anything to something with layout `inline-block`.

Comment: Nope just doesnt do anything.

Comment: Even taking out inline block still doesn't work.

Comment: `left` only matters for `position: absolute` - try giving them a negative `left-margin`

Comment: do you already wrap it inside something like `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});` or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation for jQuery `animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> Directional properties (top, right, bottom, left) **have no discernible effect on elements if their position style property is static**, which it is by default.

This is based on CSS behavior. See [CSS static and relative positioning](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_static_and_relative_positioning).

**You need to set `position: relative;` in the `.circle` CSS.**

Also the question's animation has `left: '0px'` for the first animation, so it won't go anywhere, irregardless!

Run this code snippet (button at the bottom):

```js
$('.circle').click (function () {
    $('#c1').animate ( {
        left: '20px'
    }, 200);

    $('#c2').animate ( {
        left: '285px'
    }, 200);
} );
```

```css
.loader {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 404px;
}
.circle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 7px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#c1 { background-color: #4285f4; }
#c2 { background-color: #EA4335; }
#c3 { background-color: #FCBD06; }
#c4 { background-color: #4285F4; }
#c5 { background-color: #34AA54; }
#c6 { background-color: #EA4335; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader">
    <div class="circle" id='c1'>1</div>
    <div class="circle" id='c2'>2</div>
    <div class="circle" id='c3'>3</div>
    <div class="circle" id='c4'>4</div>
    <div class="circle" id='c5'>5</div>
    <div class="circle" id='c6'>6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `left` property is to be used with absolute positioned elements, which you don't seem to have.

[w3schools CSS reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp)

Try changing a property like `background-color` so that you can clearly see the outcome.

Debugging with a `console.log` is also useful or `debugger;`

Comment: What would be a good way to move these circles around in different ways then?

Comment: You can use absolute positioning on the circle elements and then use `left` and `top` (and `'right`  and `bottom`) to move them around. Or you can stick with relative positioning (the default) and use `margin-X`.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` to your circle class. both should do it.

all the best.

Comment: OP says that jQuery doesn't do *anything*. In that case, modifying CSS styles will not help.